# Can a customized background provide two exotic languages in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, languages, background

When customizing a background, you can choose a combination of 2 languages or tool proficiencies. Is it AL-legal to pick 2 exotic languages as your background languages? I'm asking this since I don't know any other background that gives you the knowledge of two exotic languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Yes

This is directly covered in the DDAL FAQ (v. 7.1 on page 6).

> Characters may choose exotic languages from any 
>   allowed rules source, even if that rules source wasn’t 
>   used to create that character (i.e., a character 
>   created using the PHB and VGM may still choose a 
>   language from the SCAG). Druidic, thieves’ cant, 
>   monstrous languages (like Giant Eagle or Qualith),
>   and other languages that are features of a class or 
>   background are not eligible choices for this purpose